# Google maps API using SmartLocation location updates going all over the place

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, fusedlocationproviderapi, location-provider

So I'm making an app and I need continuous location updates to move my custom location marker. I wanted to have a smooth marker movement like Uber has. I implemented SmartLocation library using FusedLocationProvider, location accuracy is set to HIGH, and location is updated every second, yet for some reason I'm getting slow updates that are not accurate. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
    public void onLocationUpdatedListenerInit(){
    onLocationUpdatedListener=new OnLocationUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationUpdated(Location location) {
            animateMarker(location, myLocation);
        }
    };
}


public void startingLocationTracking(){
    LocationParams.Builder builder = new LocationParams.Builder().setAccuracy(LocationAccuracy.HIGH)
            .setDistance(0)
            .setInterval(1000);

    SmartLocation.with(this).location(new LocationGooglePlayServicesProvider()).continuous().config(builder.build()).start(onLocationUpdatedListener);
}
```

AnimateMarker method:

```
public static void animateMarker(final Location destination, final Marker marker) {
    if (marker != null) {
        final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
        final LatLng endPosition = new LatLng(destination.getLatitude(), destination.getLongitude());

        final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();

        final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator.LinearFixed();
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(1000); // duration 1 second
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                try {
                    float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                    LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, endPosition);
                    marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                    marker.setRotation(computeRotation(v, startRotation, destination.getBearing()));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // I don't care atm..
                }
            }
        });

        valueAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Marin. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please expand upon what you mean by slow updates? How frequently do you want them to occur?

Comment: Thank you, its not the frequency, once user moves it takes about 10 seconds to recognize that update